# Translating SQL into LinQ SYntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Below are my intended SQL query and I am having a hard time translating this into LinQ Method Syntax

```
select top(2) MerchantSubcriptionName,count(*) as occurence 
from MerchantSubscription 
group by MerchantSubcriptionName 
order by occurence desc
```

I am supposed to select the top 2 subscription which has the most people subscribed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this:

```cs
public class Subscription 
{
    public string MerchantSubscriptionName { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var list = _dbContext.MerchantSubscription.GroupBy(x => x.MerchantSubcriptionName)
    .Select(x => new Subscription { MerchantSubscriptionName = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
    .Take(2)
    .ToList();
```